# How can I make a button that delete an especific Task?

Tags: reactjs

im trying to build a todo list, but I really didn't get how I can make a specific button that delete an specific task,I tried to do a button for each one using .map, but I think I can made it wrong, could someone help me?

```
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <DraftsIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Tarefa 2" />
        <ListItemButton>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <DeleteIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
        </ListItemButton>
```

Comment: There's too much missing code to help. But the main idea under the delete task, is to delete the task by key in the array. 

With that said, if you have the array in a hook, you can add a function (that accepts the element's key) to the button that will remove the element from the array; and then update the state using the hook.

Comment: Thanks, i apply the concept and it worked.